# Копирование из одного массива в другой при помощи циклов

Tags: массивы, javascript, циклы

Подскажите как можно при помощи циклов сделать копирование из одного массива в другой? наглядный пример покажите, зарание спасибо

```
var myFamily = new Array(["t", "i", "m", "u", "r"], ["r", "e", "v", "i", "n"], ["a", "r", "t", "e", "m"], ["e", "l", "e", "n", "a"], ["r", "a", "i", "s", "a"]); var myFamilyReversed = new Array(); for (var i = 0; i < myFamily.length; i++) {
    document.write(myFamilyReversed[i] = myFamily[i].reverse() + "<br>");
}
```

Comment: опять вопрос непонятный. что значит копировать из одного массива в другой ? слить два массива ? почему обязательно при помощи циклов ?

Comment: @dfire, Согласно правилам форума, вопросы не должны сводиться к решению либо завершению учебных заданий за учащихся. Пожалуйста, уточните, что вы сделали сами и что не получилось.

Comment: var myFamily = new Array(["t", "i", "m", "u", "r"], ["r", "e", "v", "i", "n"], ["a", "r", "t", "e", "m"], ["e", "l", "e", "n", "a"], ["r", "a", "i", "s", "a"]);
    var myFamilyReversed = new Array();
    for (var i = 0; i < myFamily.length; i++) {

        document.write(myFamilyReversed[i] = myFamily[i].reverse() + "<br>");
    }
 нужно из массива myFamily скопировать содержимое в массив myFamilyReversed с помошью цикла. вот то что у меня получилось

Comment: зачем document.write() ? отдавайте себе отчет  в том что вы делаете

Answer (score 1):

Проще все за один раз выводить, ну и работать с копией массива (самый простой, хотя может и не самый быстрый способ это использовать метод `slice()`)

```
var myFamilyReversed = new Array(); for (var i = 0; i < myFamily.length; i++) {
        myFamilyReversed.push( myFamily[i].slice(0).reverse().join(""));
}
document.write(myFamilyReversed.join('<br>\n'));
```

но еще проще:

```
document.write(myFamily.map(function(e) {
     return e.slice(0).reverse().join("");
}).join('<br>\n');
```